# How to pass an object to JavaFX start-method

Tags: javafx, parameters

If I have a JavaFX program like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyObject myObj = new MyObject(...);
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // How to get myObj here?
```

is there any other way to get the `myObj` than making a static
attribute for parameter passing?

Comment: Why not just create `myObj` in the `start(...)` method. Some environments won't even call your `main(...)` method anyway.

Comment: The real case was a bit more complicated and the idea was based that same main function (as a code) could work both command line program and JavaFX program.  The real case was so that there was a longer initialization for the object and then a call to own `begin(myObj)` and the idea was that if the begin is override for command line and for the JavaFX.  So the question was a bit academic and can be done by doing an `initMyObj()`-method that is called from command line `main` and from JavaFX `start`.  This only breaks the idea that "this can be done without touching the main-function".